# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'mavenDescriptor'

Tags: groovy, gradle, artifactory

When using the current Artifactory gradle plugin (4.0.0) I'm getting this error. The [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) still says to do this, but maybe it is out of date? I've looked through the [source code](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/tree/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/gradle/plugin/artifactory) without success. Any pointers would be appreciated.

(edit: It looks like this may be a bug in the plugin, specifically that the [setMavenDescriptor](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/build-info-extractor-gradle-3.1.2/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/gradle/plugin/artifactory/task/BuildInfoConfigurationsTask.java#L109) method was [removed](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/gradle/plugin/artifactory/task/ArtifactoryTask.java).)